# Jquery doesn't run when page created by php

Tags: php, jquery

I would appreciate some help from others please.
I've made a development html page that loads another page into an iframe using jquery, depending on which button is pressed. This work successfully (after many hours of research on here!)
The problem comes about when the page is created using PHP (my aim is to implement the code on a more complex page, but I'm trying things out first). Although it looks fine, the jquery doesn't work when I press either button. I would appreciate some guidance from more experienced users please.
Thanks
Graham

Code--->

```
<?php
$rider1=1;
$rider2=2;
$file1="2015-07-22-19-11-52.fit";
$file2="2015-07-21-12-45-55.fit";
echo '<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Loading a page into a dialog</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
    });

    $(".session").click(function () {
        var src = $(this).data("href");
        var title = $(this).data("id");
        var $dialog = $("<div></div>")
            .html("<iframe style="border: 1px; " src="';
            echo '"+ src + "';
            echo '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>")
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 625,
                width: $(window).width() - 20,
                height: $(window).height() - 20,
                title: title
            });
            $dialog.dialog("open");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>subjects</h2>

<button class="session" data-id="#dialog1" data-href="fitanalysis.php?rider='.$rider1.'&file='.$file1.'">Rider1</button>
<br>

<button class="session" data-id="#dialog2" data-href="fitanalysis.php?rider='.$rider2.'&file='.$file2.'">Rider2</button>
<br>
</body>
</html>';
?>
```

Comment: Where is `<head>` open tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't `echo` all of your HTML like that, you can punch in and out of PHP with `<?php ...code here... ?>` anywhere.
2. No opening `<HEAD>` tag.
3. Odd string concatenation in your JavaScript.

Give this a try:

```
<?php
    $rider1 = 1;
    $rider2 = 2;
    $file1 = "2015-07-22-19-11-52.fit";
    $file2 = "2015-07-21-12-45-55.fit";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Loading a page into a dialog</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                });

                $(".session").click(function () {
                    var src = $(this).data("href");
                    var title = $(this).data("id");
                    var $dialog = $("<div></div>")
                        .html('<iframe style="border: 1px;" src="' + src + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
                        .dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            modal: true,
                            height: 625,
                            width: $(window).width() - 20,
                            height: $(window).height() - 20,
                            title: title
                        });
                        $dialog.dialog("open");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>subjects</h2>

        <button class="session" data-id="#dialog1" data-href="fitanalysis.php?rider=<?php echo $rider1; ?>&file=<?php echo $file1; ?>">Rider1</button>
        <br>

        <button class="session" data-id="#dialog2" data-href="fitanalysis.php?rider=<?php echo $rider2; ?>&file=<?php echo $file2; ?>">Rider2</button>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```